# Using an if/then statement to populate a php dropdown menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, if-statement

I'm building a dropdown menu populated from a php range of numbers.  My code works so far.  Here's how I've written it so far:

```
      <?php
    echo "<select name='Strength_Pts2' id='Strength_Pts2'>";
    foreach($PotRange as $AttributesAvailable) 
    {
        echo "<option value='$AttributesAvialabe'>$AttributesAvailable</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Now, I'd like to add an If/Then condition to the menu, so under certain circumstances the user will only get an option of '0' instead of the whole range.  Here's what I coded:

```
         <?php
    echo "<select name='Strength_Pts2' id='Strength_Pts2'>";
    if ( 1 == 1 ) {
foreach($PotRange as $AttributesAvailable) 
    {
        echo "<option value='$AttributesAvialabe'>$AttributesAvailable</option>";
    }
    else
echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

I've tried it with and without a ; after the last }.  I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE on line 531.

Can anybody help out with what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, -CB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot some curly braces, use the following:

```
<?php
  echo "<select name='Strength_Pts2' id='Strength_Pts2'>";
    if ( 1 == 1 ) {
      foreach($PotRange as $AttributesAvailable) {
        echo "<option value='$AttributesAvialabe'>$AttributesAvailable</option>";
      }
    } else {
      echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
    }
  echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: You guys are fast and awesome.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, keep indentation as a priority to avoid errors in the future. It makes reading and editing the code way easier too. Happy coding!

Comment: A related quick question; when I use this menu to select a value in a mysql insert function, the value doesn't read as the number I select, but instead reads as NULL.  Can anybody think of any reason that would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Missing an open and close brace after the else.

Change it to:

```
<?php
echo "<select name='Strength_Pts2' id='Strength_Pts2'>";
if ( 1 == 1 ) {
  foreach($PotRange as $AttributesAvailable) 
   {
        echo "<option value='$AttributesAvialabe'>$AttributesAvailable</option>";
    }
    else
}
{

    echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket for you if statement:

```
....
if ( 1 == 1 ) {
    foreach($PotRange as $AttributesAvailable) 
    {
        echo "<option value='$AttributesAvialabe'>$AttributesAvailable</option>";
    }
}else //you were missing closing brace here
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (...) {
    foreach (...) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

You are missing the `}` of the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not styled well and you have a problem with curly brackets

```
      <?php
    echo "<select name='Strength_Pts2' id='Strength_Pts2'>";
    if ( 1 == 1 ) {
        foreach($PotRange as $AttributesAvailable) 
        {
               echo "<option value='$AttributesAvialabe'>$AttributesAvailable</option>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
      echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

?>

I recommend u to use tab indents to have a good styled and readable code